# What's the command for ssh to find files which *.png and download them

Tags: command-line, ssh

I was connected my OpenSSH, but What's the command for ssh to find all files which are *.png and get them at the same time, recursively

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can list files of your interest with `ssh`, then download them with `scp`:

```
ssh user@host find /remote_path -iname '*.png' | 
  while read pngfile; do 
    scp user@host:"$pngfile" /local_path
  done
```

All `*.png` files under `/remote_path` will be downloaded to `/local_path`, but the remote directory structure will not be created (all files will be put in the same directory), so you may have problems if you have two files with the same name in different directories.

**Edit**

The remote `find` command line should be corrected in this way:

```
find /remote_path -iname "'*.png'"
```

where the internal pair of single quotes are needed to avoid local shell pathname expansion of `*`, wheras the external pair of double quotes are needed to avoid remote shell pathname expansion of `*`.

The two types of quotes could be exchanges, and other syntaxes could be used, like `\''*.png'\'`, `\""*.png"\"` or `"\"*.png\""`.

If you don't have .png in remote home directory, there is no difference between the two commands, but it is better to be safe.

Comment: Thanks, What's programming language at your "while" statement?

Comment: It is a `bash` statement, present also in other shells, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide

Comment: 1. unless you have keys, you will have to provide password for each file. 2. this is very slow solution. 3. will not work if file name has space

Comment: if you want to transfer multiple files, you can user "-r" for scp, but solution with tar will be faster anyway.

Comment: @Michał Šrajer: corrected the spaces problem. Moreover, `-r` will get whole directories, I think, not only desired file types.

Comment: @enzotib: you can transfer whole dirs with "-r", but you can also transfer many files at once: scp -r remote1.png remote2.png remote3.png /local/dir/. But this is slower than tar solution.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way I know is to create tar.gz remotely, transfer it via SSH and untar locally:

```
ssh user@remotehost 'find /remote/path/ -name "*.png" -print0 2>/dev/null | xargs -0 tar cfz - ' | tar xvfz -
```

This will work with filenames with spaces and is faster than `scp -r` and much faster than `scp` for each file.

Comment: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'

Comment: also when syntactically correct, it breaks on filenames with spaces.

Comment: fixed. now it deals with filenames with spaces and it's faster than the other solution.

Comment: It could be shortened to: `ssh user@remotehost 'find /remote/path/ -name "*.png" | tar -T- cfz - ' | tar xvfz -`

Comment: @enzotib: I didn't know -T-. Nice trick. However, it does not work: tar: You must specify one of the `-Acdtrux' or `--test-label'  options

Comment: ok, it needs `-czf -` instead of `cfz -`